# Aggregation on varchar thats casted to decimal doesnot give correct answer

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

Recently we had a report generation issue where aggregation (`SUM()`) was performed on varchar values.
These values are man hours stored which are integer values eg :456.9.
Since we are into maintainence,its not possible to change the table design.
After some research i modified the query by adding some explicit casting.

```
select ts.changedto as CHANGEDSTATE,
    cast(sum(coalesce(cast(trim(tw.estimatedhours) AS DECIMAL(5,2)),0)) AS UNSIGNED) as ESTIMATEDHOURS,        
    cast(sum(coalesce(cast(trim(tw.actualhours) AS DECIMAL(5,2)),0)) AS UNSIGNED) as ACTUALHOURS
    from tstatechange ts
                  left outer join tworkitem tw on (ts.workitemkey=tw.workitemkey)
                       left outer join tprojcat pc on (tw.prOJCATKEY = pc.pKEY)
                             where (ts.changedto = '8') and ts.lastedit between '2012-02-01  00:00:00' and '2012-02-28 23:59:59'
                                   and pc.projkey = 39 group by CHANGEDSTATE;
```

Even this query is returning wrong values.
For example for these values manual summation

```
(89.35
96
11.15
0
0.1
92
1
609.05
61.25
0.5
1
0.5)
```

yields 961.9 but the query return 963.
Can anyone help me out with this. Is there any special function or any other work arounds ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query suffers from rounding. Those two 0.5 probably become two 1s. giving 963. What database do you use?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. The database we use is mysql 5.1 (InnoDB).

Comment: I converted each of the varchar to decimal values, does mysql  round off those values ?If any round off occurs i expect it to happen after summation.

Comment: Well i removed the outermost cast and it returns 962.9! Which means the 0.5 values are actually round off!

Comment: If you get decimals then my intuition was way off. What happens if you leave cast to decimal(5,2) only?

Comment: When i removed the inner cast i get 963.

Comment: Sorry, I ment what if you remove sum and unsigned parts? Do you get your numbers?

Comment: Nope.I get some vague numbers.

Comment: Could you post numbers you get from *cast(trim(tw.estimatedhours) AS DECIMAL(5,2))*

Comment: Estimated Hour 88.00 Actualhours 92.00

Comment: Please post a list of tw.estimatedhours or tw.actualhours as you did in your original post. I need to see if varchars differ from decimals. *select ts.changedto as CHANGEDSTATE, tw.estimatedhours,
    cast(trim(tw.estimatedhours) as decimal(5,2)) from ...*

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which SQL server you are using, but I can't repeat this on MS SQL Server 2008R2. Are you sure that your query returns the data that you've listed?

```
select '89.35' as x
into #tmp
union all select '96'
union all select '11.15 '
union all select null 
union all select '0.10 '
union all select '92.00 '
union all select '1.00 '
union all select '609.05'
union all select '61.25 '
union all select '0.50'
union all select '1 '
union all select '0.50 '


select sum(coalesce(cast(ltrim(rtrim(x)) AS DECIMAL(5,2)),0))
from #tmp  -- Yields 961.9

select cast(sum(coalesce(cast(ltrim(rtrim(x)) AS DECIMAL(5,2)),0)) AS INT)
from #tmp  -- Yields 961

select 89.35+96.0+11.15+0.0+0.1+92.0+1.0+609.05+61.25+0.5+1.0+0.5 -- Yields 961.9
```

SQL Server doesn't have UNSIGNED type, so I've used INT.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your input .We use mysql (innoDB) as our database.My mistake since i did not mention it.

Comment: Well the first 3 queries dont work in mysql.As for the last one it yields 961.9

Comment: I've tagged your post with MySql - please do this in future as it will help narrow down the issue.